# Library that converts xml to a visual Swing tree?

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: How to display an XML file in a JTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011775/java-how-to-display-an-xml-file-in-a-jtree)

Is there any library that will parse an xml file and create a collapsable visual tree for Swing? Sort of like JTree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://www.arsitech.com/xml/jdom_xml_jtree.php

http://www.developer.com/xml/article.php/3731356/Displaying-XML-in-a-Swing-JTree.htm