# Java: How to display XML Data in Tree View?

Tags: java

I am new to Java Development. Currently, I am reading an XML File and now want to display the contents on UI in Tree Like Structure. For UI, I am using NetBeans. Where do I start with, in order to display data in above said format?

Comment: Jame: could you ask a more specific question?

Comment: You might need [JTree](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html).Here is link for: [How to work with trees in java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

Comment: Something like that? http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/XMLTreeView.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to display an XML file in a JTree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011775/java-how-to-display-an-xml-file-in-a-jtree)

Comment: This is a *challenge* for everyone who is new to Java Development.

Answer (score 0):

in Netbeans you need to create a project, add the .xml file inside and then you will be to natively visualize your .xml file inside the project's files window. The second option is to use the navigator tab [window > navigating > navigator]
Best regards