# How can I show a XML file graphically in a JTree using DOM?

Tags: java, xml, dom, jtree

I don't want it to be editable, I just need it to visualize the file. No idea how to go about it though.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Looked at any libraries? Looked at how JTree operates?

Comment: I tried the method provided in this thread, without much success, since I don't quite get what it's doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011775/java-how-to-display-an-xml-file-in-a-jtree

Comment: Can you edit in snippets of what you've tried and didn't understand? With that info, this question can be answered to better help you both achieve your task *and* learn from it at the same time.